# Profile option for sticky header

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, top-bar

I'd like to request a profile option that allows the header to be sticky.

Often I am scrolling and scrolling and scrolling and I'll hit question number 80 something and start seeing old questions that I've already seen. I'll often want to go to another network or check my profile or search for something specific and that requires scrolling aaaaaall the way back up to the top of the page.

I think it would be beneficial for a lot of people to at least have the option to have a sticky header.

Comment: I agree with this as well, but perhaps it needs to be on the Stack Exchange Meta instead of here?

Comment: There's a userscript floating around that does this, see [this answer](http://stackapps.com/a/6881). Also see [this discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/101385/179041) on Meta SE for the same proposal from a few years back

Comment: @Robotnik Thanks for looking into this for me. I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The top bar is now sticky by default.

In addition, there is now a setting to disable the stickiness in your [profile settings](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current), under Site Settings -> Preferences -> Navigation:

[image: Disable top bar stickiness]

Answer (score 3):

This is [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned).

Stack Overflow is currently [testing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343103) a new top navigation bar which is sticky by default. A Stack Overflow employee [announced](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343268) that at some point, a similar navigation bar will be designed for use on the other Stack Exchange sites.

For now, Robotnik already mentioned [this user script](https://stackapps.com/a/6881) to make the current top bar sticky. I've never tried it.

**Update**: In response to feedback about the new navigation bar on Meta Stack Overflow, there is now an [option](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343483) to make it sticky or non-sticky. I would expect this same option to be available here, once the new navigation bar is released.